# My duplicate question got deleted; why and how to improve it?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, specific-question, deleted-questions

I answered [my own question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37294186/auto-generated-sample-list-contains-all-the-same-elements) after doing some research. Later it was marked as a duplicate (which is fine for me). I even got some upvotes on the answer. But the question got deleted.

I now want to undelete the question. Could there be any specific reason it got deleted? Having 2 downvotes doesn't seem harsh enough to warrant deletion, especially if there's an upvoted answer to it.

For sub-10K users, here are the question and answer:

[image: question]

---

[image: answer]

Comment: Why do you want to undelete it? Your answer is the exact same as the one found in the dupe target under the heading `Adding the Same Object`.

Comment: @Rob So basically, my answer looks to be a copy of that answer?

Comment: No, not a copy - I meant it explains the same problem - but what is the benefit of the answer? What does the site gain? If you believe your answer is better/different, post the answer on the duplicate target.

Comment: @Rob The dupe target doesn't seem to be a good question - It looks as if the answerer just came out of the blue with something(like static fields, or adding the same object). In reality, the code was deleted through editing. As the question is now, I have nothing to answer to.

Comment: Why? We already have that question once, we do not need the same question twice.

Comment: @cst1992 So why don't you improve that question?

Answer (score 7):

Note that the duplicate states

> Note: this is designed to be a canonical Q&A for the numerous similar issues that arise on this site.

In other words, you're not the first one to ask the question, nor is the dupe target. Plenty have come before it with the community finally stepping in and saying "enough is enough, let's have a clear target to close all these questions against".

At that point it should be clear that no further posts along the same line are wanted or needed.

Now, if you feel that the duplicate has an unclear question, either improve it, or work with the OP to have it improved. But there is no reason to undelete your questions.

Answer (score 0):

I *really* feel like the duplicate [covers what you're asking about](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19843507/1079354).

I personally wouldn't want it reopened, but I also adamantly disagree with it being deleted, since that post isn't causing any immediate harm or confusion to the extent that it has to be removed from the site.

Maybe the deletion needs to be reevaluated in this one, but I save that for a broader topic on the matter.  It's tough to say *why* it was deleted without roping those three in here to explain.

Comment: I did lose rep on the answer - I got a -30. However, I didn't get a +4 for the deleted downvotes. http://i.stack.imgur.com/4YkrH.png

Comment: The post is adding nothing of value.  It's just one more of a question asked thousands of times, adding nothing new.  The internet is a better place with it gone.  Rewarding people for providing the 2,000th low quality duplicate to a common problem is counter productive to a site trying to be a useful repository of knowledge.